# What's the difference between these two sentences?

Tags: verbs, differences, adjectives, syntactic-analysis

> 1. Health facilities reported 1000 people killed and 3000 wounded since March 19.
> 2. Health facilities reported that 1000 people were killed and 3000 were wounded since March 19.

Isn't 'killed' an adjective in the first sentence and a verb in the second? I'd be grateful if anyone could please explain in detail. Thank you.

Comment: Essentially, they're the same sentence, the first one with deducible words deleted. It becomes a meaningless exercise reclassifying 'ex past participles'.

Comment: See [Word order of participial modiﬁers and proper nouns](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182968/word-order-of-participial-modi%EF%AC%81ers-and-proper-nouns/183047#183047), and John Lawler's posts on deletions. Although I seem to have weakened and called the things 'adjectives' there. But try 'reported 1000 people tall'!

Comment: You might want to also consider that the first construction is common in journalism, especially for headlines. The second is more formal and a real sentence structure.

Comment: Or try replacing the "wounded" in #1 with "stole"...

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of elision: Both sentences use the past participle, but elements of the sentence have been left out for the sake of brevity in the first example. The rather terse style of #1 seems much like that of TV news shows, which generally try to cram as many stories into a programme slot as possible.

Consider that you could insert the phrase "by the fighting" after the word "wounded" - each sentence would carry the same meaning.